# How do I send a YouTube video from my desktop to my Android tablet?

Tags: linux, youtube

Apps such as YouTube and Netflix use the X protcol to conect to smart TVs so you can send (a link to) the video you're watching to the TV, and it starts playing on the TV right away. I'm looking for something like the reverse of this: if I've started watching a video on the YouTube website on my Ubuntu PC, I'd like to have that start playing on my tablet (e.g. so I can take it with me to the kitchen as I cook). Ideally, it should start playing on the tablet at the same point I was at on the website.

The simplest workaround I can think of would be to use the "Watch later" playlist to save the video, and then open it on the tablet. That's quite long-winded, and I'm hoping there's something easier.

Comment: There is an app to send tabs to the pc from a phone (and many other features, see below), but unfortunately I too have yet to figure out a way that is not also the "watch later" workaround. Of course, if YouTube cared about designing a decent user experience simple things like this would already have been part of the platform for a decade. But they believe providing a barely functional UI will inspire users to buy into their various branch subscription packages... If I have to install some extension for the simple task of inverting a playlist there is something wrong with that sites UI....

Answer (score 1):

Hi after googling today in 2022, I find this useful project:
https://github.com/pdf/kdeconnect-chrome-extension

[image]

It's an extension for chrome/firefox and a binary, It let you push links to phone/tablet and opens browser if no handler defined, or app, e.g.: youtube.

I tested in Vivaldi/Brave and a Amazon Fire 10, works flawlessly.

- NOTE: You must have installed "KDE Connect" in both sides, PC (Windows and Linux) and Android,It might work on Apple devices, I didn't test on those. This KDE connect browser extension is like a plugin for KDE Connect and is not part of the original project.

Comment: Can confirm at least the utilitarian effectiveness of KDEconnect. I use it on all my devices and my linux rig. I use it regularly to send files (datasheet pdfs, or images usually) to and from the desktop, and to send webpages on my phones chrome browser to my pcs chrome browser (hit the three buttons, share, "send to device" icon with KDE logo. Easy peasy). Also has a virtual keyboard/mouse plugin to control your pc from not at the desk, as well as a host of other features. Can be a bit of a bear to find and set all the options, and YMMV, but I am a happy user, and recommend giving it a try

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/939701) suggests that, if you run Firefox on both desktop and mobile, you can sync tabs between the two.  I should note that I haven't done it myself, but I use Chrome on both my devices and the feature works great for me.

Comment: I had a go of that, but `about:sync-tabs` only works on desktop Firefox, and gives "The address isn't valid" on Android.